# sed regex isses on AIX (part 2)

Tags: regex, unix, sed, aix

I am trying to execute this command on AIX:

```
sed 's/\([a-Z]*\),.*/\1/' config >config.new
```

where config is a file with the following format:

```
item1,file1
item2,file2
```

but I always get the following error:

```
sed: 0602-404 Function s/\([a-Z]*\),.*/\1/ cannot be parsed.
```

I suspect there is something wrong with the regex, but it worked fine on a SUN platform.

Comment: did this produces any output ? `sed 's/\([a-Z]*\),.*/\1/' config`

Comment: Maybe escape the `/`...

Comment: No, it didn't. It just gives that error.

Comment: No, that doesn't help either.

Comment: I don't like your [a-Z] so much, please try and replace by [a-zA-Z] or [[:alpha:]] and see if it works. Maybe that's where your trouble comes from...

Answer (score 1):

You want to keep all before the comma. Instead you could remove all after the comma:

```
  's/,.*//g'
```

The problem with your expression could be `[a-Z]`, where a is ASCII 97 and Z is ASCII 90.

If you need the `\1` you can also use `[^,]` (all but comma)

```
  's/\([^,]*\),.*/\1/'
```

Comment: If so, also `cut -d',' -f1 file` would make it.

Answer (score 0):

Z comes before a so your range is backwards.  Either do: A-z or a-zA-Z as has been suggested.

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem.